# Why this function would get a signed integer overflow?

Tags: c++, integer, bit-manipulation, overflow

I get a signed integer overflow when I call this function with a large number:

```
int count_bit(long long num) {
    int cnt=0;
    while(num>0) {
        if(num&1 == 1) cnt++;
        num>>1;
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

it give me `2147483647 + 1 cannot be represented in type 'int'` such error, I don't know where in this function would cause a integer overflow. Since I already use long long for num and count is not that large.

Comment: Do you know C++ has an inbuild function (since C++20) for this? [std::pop_count](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/popcount). Or pre C++20 there is [std::bitset::count](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/count)

Comment: Note that right-shift of negative value is implementation specific.

Comment: stepping through the code in a debugger would have led you to correct your understanding of its operation. please use this opportunity to learn to use a debugger. it's not as daunting as it sounds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integer overflow in your code is caused by the comparison `(num&1 == 1)`within the if statement. The bitwise AND operator `(&)` has lower precedence than the equality operator `(==)`, so the expression is evaluated as `(num & (1 == 1))`.

In C++, the result of a comparison operation is either 0 (false) or 1 (true). Since you're performing a bitwise AND operation with `num` and the result of the comparison, the value of `(1 == 1)` is 1, and you effectively perform `num & 1` in each iteration of the loop.

You forgot to assign the shifted value back to the num variable within the while loop. So thats why the value of num remains unchanged, causing an infinite loop when num is greater than 0. This also leads to the integer overflow error you're experiencing.

You need to assign the shifted value back to num using the assignment operator `(num = num >> 1)`.

```
int count_bit(long long num) {
    int cnt = 0;
    while (num > 0) {
        if ((num & 1) == 1) cnt++;
        num = num >> 1;  // Assign the shifted value back to 'num'
    }
    return cnt;
}
```

With this, the code should work as expected and prevent the integer overflow error.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: i made some changes. i forgot about those brackets. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: `if (num & 1)` happens to be equivalent to `if ((num & 1) == 1)` so though the code isn't what they intended it still works correctly

Comment: This appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Among other issues, I received an extremely similar answer back from ChatGPT, down to the comment `// Assign the right-shifted value back to num` being nearly identical. If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it, as [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831).

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was AI-generated, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify issues.

Comment: This is probably ChatGPT-generated text, slightly modified before posting revision 1.

Comment: at one point, this post had 6 upvotes. I'm surprised that many people (on these tags especially!) just hand those out like candy, no validation, no critical reading. I can understand an asker just "accepting" such an answer because askers, by the nature of needing to ask in the first place, may not be able to tell if an answer is *correct*... but all the other upvotes should have known better.

Answer (score 2):

The integer overflow in your code is ***not caused*** by the expression `(num & 1 == 1)`

---

The result of your shift isn't stored anywhere. You should have written `num >>= 1;`

I'll take that to be a ***typo***. Without that typo, your code would have worked.

Because of that, `num` is never actually reduced or changed in any way. The loop condition never changes. For most inputs (all except 0), it will always be true. You now have an **infinite loop**.

If `num` is odd, this infinite loop will continually increment `cnt`, which will eventually **overflow**. With even `num`, it'll just be an infinite loop without causing an overflow.

And there's the operator precedence issue others have pointed out, but that, luckily, *has no effect*. No matter what the precedence is, the result is always equivalent to `num & 1`.